# Azure Powershell SQL DataBase Export to Storage Container gets "An Error Occurred while Sending the Request"

Tags: database, azure, request, export

I'd appreciate any help, even if it's just to suggest a way to diagnose the situation.  The error message isn't really helping.

I've built a new VM from which I'm running PowerShell scripts to backup my databases.  It had worked before on an old server for several months, and worked once on the new server, then I upgraded my Azure PowerShell cmdlets, and haven't been able to get it to work again. Mostly it says "An Error Occurred while sending the request", although twice it's said "Error Copying Content to a Stream" instead.

Below is my source code, with sensitive stuff replaced with ?'s.  When I display the $stctx and $dbctx, they seem to have reasonable values.  I added the IP address of the server as an exception to the db firewall, and I've installed SQL Server Management Studio and verified that I can connect to the database.

Here are the two error messages that I get:

```
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport : An error occurred while sending the request.
At C:\Users\Public\PublicCmds\test.ps1:29 char:1
+ Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $dbctx -StorageContext $stctx ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport],      
HttpRequestException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :    
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Database.Cmdlet.StartAzureSqlDatabaseExport
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport : Error while copying content to a stream.
At C:\Users\Public\PublicCmds\test.ps1:29 char:1
+ Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $dbctx -StorageContext $stctx ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport], HttpRequestException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Database.Cmdlet.StartAzureSqlDatabaseExport
```

Here is a sanitized version of the source code:

```
param($dbname)

if ($dbname -eq $null) {
    write-host "Database code must be specified"
return
}

$password = "????????" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$servercredential = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("????", $password) 

$dbsize = 1
$dbrestorewait = 10
$dbserver = "????"
$stacct = $dbcode

$stkey = "????????"

$stctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $stacct -StorageAccountKey $stkey
$dbctx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $dbserver -Credential $servercredential 

$dt = Get-Date
$timestamp = "_" + $dt.Year + "-" + ("{0:D2}" -f $dt.Month) + "-" + ("{0:D2}" -f $dt.Day) + "-" +  ("{0:D2}" -f $dt.Hour) + ("{0:D2}" -f $dt.Minute)
$bkupname = $dbname + $timestamp + ".bacpac"
write-host "db context"
$dbctx
write-host "storage context"
$stctx
write-host "Backup $dbname to $bkupname"
Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $dbctx -StorageContext $stctx -   StorageContainerName databasebackup  -DatabaseName $dbname -BlobName $bkupname
```

Answer (score 1):

I made two changes that together fixed the problem:
- There was an error in the filename (wish the error message said as much)
- I changed to using AD security (the free kind)